# create 2 vectors from 1 in R

Tags: r, design-patterns, matching

I am using base R trying to split the following character string into 2:

```
some_text | number1 (number2) | number1 (number2) | number1 (number2)

vec1 <- number1 number1 number1 

vec2 <- number2 number2 number2
```

I have been able to remove the `some_text` and the `|` symbol but need help creating the vectors based on pattern matching.

Comment: Is it a single string?  Try `m1 <- lapply(strsplit(str1, "[ |()]"), function(x) matrix(x[x!=""][-1], ncol=2, byrow= TRUE))[[1]]; vec1 <- m1[,1]; vec2 <- m1[,2]`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit`, `sub`, and `apply`:

```
x <- "some_text | 1 (2) | 3 (4) | 5 (6)"
y <- strsplit(x, "\\s*\\|\\s*", perl=TRUE)
number1 <- sapply(y, function(x) { sub(" \\(\\d+\\)", "", x) })[2:4]
number2 <- sapply(y, function(x) { sub("\\d+ \\((\\d+)\\)", "\\1", x) })[2:4]

number1
number2

[1] "1" "3" "5"
[1] "2" "4" "6"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` with `strsplit`

```
m1 <- lapply(strsplit(str1, "[ |()]"), function(x)
                  matrix(x[x!=""][-1], ncol=2, byrow= TRUE))[[1]]
vec1 <- m1[,1]
vec2 <- m1[,2] 
vec1
#[1] "number1" "number1" "number1"

vec2
#[1] "number2" "number2" "number2"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'some_text | number1 (number2) | number1 (number2) | number1 (number2)'
```

Comment: Your ability to come up with these one-liners never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: This is working but I get this error: data length [13] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [7]

Comment: @Alex This is based on your example and it is working for me